# Why can't I create a 3d scatter plot in Python on my desktop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, data-science

I am trying to use the 3D scatter plot object in python. And I have successfully done this on my laptop. However, I can not copy and paste code onto my desktop. When I do this I get an error. I will attach my the section of my code below that is giving me trouble. I am using Anaconda to run my code. I will note that my laptop uses python 3.6 and my desktop uses 3.7, but I do not think that is causing it. The error I is get is as follows. "ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'"

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import time
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import multiprocessing as mp
from obj_class import objective_class
import pdb
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def create3d():
    grid_matrix = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    p = ax.scatter3D(grid_matrix[:,0],grid_matrix[:,1] ,grid_matrix[:,2] , c=grid_matrix[:,3], cmap='viridis')
    cb = fig.colorbar(p) 
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    ax.set_title(' Scatter Plot')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a `3d` projection in `matplotlib <= 3.1` you need to import [`axes3d`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html), i.e.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

From `matplotlib >= 3.2`, no extra import is necessary. So possibly you are running different matplotlib versions on both computers.

If you are running your code within an iPython kernel, Jupyter notebook for example, 
then you only need to perform each import once and you will be able to run any code which relies on said import until the kernel is shutdown. However, in order to run the script in a self contained fashion you will need that import included in your script.

Comment: @RyanJ I’m glad my answer helped, be sure to mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question is marked as such for future users

Comment: Thank you. You helped me solve a slightly different, but related problem, which had crept in at Python 3.12. "From matplotlib >= 3.2, no extra import is necessary." I had inherited the import from some old code, which started to break at 3.12 (oddly enough, only with Wing IDE, not under command line". You inspired me to take out the import, which fixed the problem....